# Ordering SQL results by more than one dynamic condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that selects some users based on certain conditions (namely, having the same value, expressed in points, in a cell in the `drivers_standings` table) and orders them based on their lowest value (`position`) in another table (`results`).

```
$superquer = "
    SELECT SD.driver, MIN(R.position) AS highest_position FROM standings_drivers SD 
        INNER JOIN results R ON R.driverId = SD.driver 
    WHERE R.compId='$compId' AND R.eventID>='$firstevent' 
        AND R.eventID<='$lastevent' AND R.eventSession NOT IN ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA')
        AND SD.season = '42' AND SD.points='$points_pos' 
    GROUP BY SD.driver 
    ORDER BY MIN(R.position)";
```

However, I have cases in which both have the same value AND also the lowest `position`. What I am trying to achieve is finding a way to make it look at the next lowest value, and then the next, and the next until a difference is found.

For example, what I have now is:

```
User A: 56 points, best result 9th
User B: 56 points, best result 6th
User C: 56 points, best result 7th

---> User B, User C, User A
```

However, I have also cases like this:

```
User A: 56 points, best result 4th
User B: 56 points, best result 6th
User C: 56 points, best result 4th
```

In this case, User A and User C are to be ordered by their second best result, so if it was:

```
User A: 56 points, best result 4th, second best 5th
User B: 56 points, best result 6th, second best 9th
User C: 56 points, best result 4th, second best 4th
```

We would order them like this:

```
--- > User C, User A, User B
```

NOTE: the second best result COULD be the same as the best result - all users took part in several events and there is nothing to prevent them achieving the same ranking in more than one.

Of couse, since I am using the sql MIN function, I don't know how to code it so that it would look for the next best result and ONLY for those whose best result is the same.

Comment: You may want to narrow down the RDBMS selection. Are we talking MySQL?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes, MySQL. Not really sure what you mean by "narrowing down the RDBMS selection" - does this answer?

Comment: Yes, the reason it's good to say MySQL instead of just SQL in your question is that once queries get a bit more advanced, MySQL has some limitations one needs to know about when building the query.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thank you - went to edit the tags but Alexei did it already :)

Comment: Is there any maximum value to the position a user can have in a result? (max number of participants?)

Comment: I updated my answer based on group_concat; that should do the job nicely without the need for a dynamic number of joins. Nice question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make the query loop for the maximum number of events in this fashion:

```
        $orderbit = "ORDER BY position1";
        $superquer = "SELECT SD.driver, 

             COALESCE((SELECT R.position FROM results R 
             WHERE R.driverId = SD.driver AND R.compId='$compId' 
             AND R.eventID>='$firstevent' AND R.eventID<='$lastevent' 
             AND R.eventSession NOT IN ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA') 
             ORDER BY R.position 
             LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0), 999) AS position1";

             $i=2;
             $max = $totalsessions+1;

            while ($i<$max) {

                $superquer .= ", COALESCE((SELECT R$i.position FROM results R$i 
             WHERE R$i.driverId = SD.driver AND R$i.compId='$compId' 
             AND R$i.eventID>='$firstevent' AND R$i.eventID<='$lastevent' 
             AND R$i.eventSession NOT IN ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA') 
             ORDER BY R$i.position 
             LIMIT 1 OFFSET $i), 999) AS position$i";

                $orderbit .= ", position$i";

                $i++;
            }                

        $superquer .= " FROM standings_drivers SD 
        WHERE SD.season = '42' AND SD.points='$points_pos'";

        $orderbit .= ";";

        $querytotl = "$superquer $orderbit";
```

This is an evolution of @NineBerry's code so thank you for all the contributions!

Comment: How many sessions will you have at the most? This could become a large query. You might even bump into the limits of MySql.

Comment: @trincot the maximum number of sessions to include tends to be 3, with the number of events rarely exceeding 20. Hopefully well within the limits :)

Comment: Ah, ok, that works. A bit confusing though that you start saying: *loop for the maximum number of events*, but name your variable *$totalsessions*. I still think my suggested query is a nicer solution though ;-)

Comment: @trincot I am definitely going to try your solution - looks much more elegant than what I came up with :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use separate subqueries to query the first and second best results for each user.

```
select SD.driver,  

    coalesce((select R.Position from results R 
     where R.driverId = SD.driver and R.compId='$compId' 
     and R.eventID>='$firstevent' and R.eventID<='$lastevent' 
     and R.eventSession not in ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA') 
     order by R.Position 
     limit 1 offset 0), 999999) as best_position,

    coalesce((select R2.Position from results R2 
     where R2.driverId = SD.driver and R2.compId='$compId' 
     and R2.eventID>='$firstevent' and R2.eventID<='$lastevent' 
     and R2.eventSession not in ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA') 
     order by R2.Position 
     limit 1 offset 1), 999999) as second_best_position

from standings_drivers SD 
where SD.season = '42' and SD.points='$points_pos' 
order by best_position, second_best_position;
```

Not tested, so may contain some syntax errors.

We use two subqueries to find all results for each driver, order the results by position and then use the limit clause to get the first or the second row only respectively.

We use coalesce() on the returned result of the subquery so that when the subquery returns NULL (which means the user has no further result), the position is returned as 999999.

This way we get a result set of drivers with their best and second best result as separate columns and can easily order by these columns.

Comment: Thank you! This should be a good way, but do you reckon there is a way to make it so that it keeps going until the tie is broken?

Comment: That would be too complex for a single sql query. Either use a stored procedure in MySQL or get the relevant data via sql and do the sorting in PHP.

Comment: I think that'd be out of my skill range - I will try the above and see how it goes!

Comment: A hint: You should pay attention to when you get to a position where one of the players has no more results to count. How will you sort then?

Comment: Yeah, that is another problem I have to grapple with, as players have taken part in different numbers of events. In the case one of them has taken part in fewer events than the other he is compared to, he'd end up behind (as even finishing last is better than a no-show).

Comment: (for completeness's sake, if both players had taken part in the same number of events, scored the same points and finished in the same positions, there would be the pre-event qualifying to take into account - and should that be the same as well, coin toss. But we're getting into the hypothetical here :) )

Comment: I have enhanced the sql statement to give users a bad placing (999999) when they have no further result.

Comment: Thank you - I am making some adjustments so hopefully I will be able to show you something soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the use of [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). It concatenates the position values in ascending order per driver, formatting each position in 3 digits. Then it appends a `z` to it when sorting, so that drivers with fewer results will end up last in a tie:

```sql
select   driverId, score
from
          (select   driverId, 
                    group_concat(
                        lpad(position, 3, '0')
                        order by position) AS score
          from      results
          group by  driverId) as drivers
order by  score || 'z'
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/392d7/12)

This solution has no practical limitation in precision as it is string based: a series of a thousand positions is no problem. Just make sure the number of digits used per position (`3`) is set correctly. As I assume this is not about races with many hundreds of drivers, I guess `3` should be just right.

Doing this with one sub query, like above, will have far petter performance than having a sub query per race (session).

Also be aware that in MySql the maximum number of tables joined in a `FROM` clause is [limited to 61](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/joins-limits.html), meaning a pure join-based solution can only look at that many events (sessions) before it runs into an exception.